I want a int input varible then cnvert it to string
So i wanted to convert an int(input('Enter an integer') to str. because i wanted to code that if the user inputed a letter the python would print out this ('Error'). The reason im doing this is i was wondering if im able to do it without the use of the .isdigit() method or the "try" keyword.
letters = 'a-z' (just imagine all the letters)

user = int(input('>'))

if user >= 52:
     blank += 1

if user in letters:
     print(errro)


Am i allowed to post my code here? im new srry
but basically if the user input a letter I want python to kinda recognized it not um syntax error.

You need to check if the input is a number before you convert it to an int. You also need to consider characters that are not alphanumeric.

so i have to manually put int() in my codes? can i not just str() the the second one?

input always returns str. You can save it to variable without converting to int, check if its a letter and only then convert to number.

the first line contains invalid syntax, your second line is missing a closing quote that messes everything up. blank is not defined so you cannot increase it. errro is not defined so you cannot print it

If you don't want to use str.isdigit() or any kind of exception handling then you could do this to confirm that the user input is comprised solely of digits 0-9
v = input("> ")

if not all(c in "0123456789" for c in v):
    print("Invalid input")

Note:
This is not the "right" way. Better to call int() on the input string and handle any ValueError exception that arises

You can just use the str converter func of python:
letters = 'a-z' (just imagine all the letters)

user = int(input('>'))

if user >= 52:
     blank += 1

if str(user) in letters:
     print(errro)

If you want to deal with uppercase letters, you can probably use the lower method, too:
letters = 'a-z' (just imagine all the letters)

user = int(input('>'))
    
if user >= 52:
     blank += 1
    
if str(user).lower() in letters:
     print(errro)

Hope this help!

This makes no sense. The input is passed to int() Thus, if there is no exception, user must be an integer. Therefore, if letters is the alphabet, the in letters test will never be True

Something like this may fit your needs:
import string

user = input('>') # do not convert "user" to integer initially

if user in string.ascii_lowercase: # if user is a lowercase letter...
    print('It is a lowercase letter.') # print the corresponding message
else: # otherwise...
     user = int(user) # convert "user" to an integer
     if user >= 52: # if statement from your original code
         blank += 1


This makes no sense. If the input is, for example, "cba" then user in string.ascii_lowercase will be False and the call to int() will raise a ValueError exception

@SIGHUP I was just emulating the OP’s original code of if user in letters:
